# How to fix “ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)”

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, softmax

I am trying to do sentiment analysis on a german tweet-data-set with the bert-base-german-cased modell which i imported over transformers from hugginface.

To be able to calculate the predicted probabilities i want to Softmax of Numpy and here does the issue begin.

```
F.softmax(model(input_ids, attention_mask), dim=1)
```

I got the error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Does anyone know, which values are here expected?

All works  when i try to run it with:

```
self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)
```

getting the error when i switch to

```
self.bert = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained("bert-base-german-cased")
```

As you can probaly see, i am a noob. therefore I please ask for simple and detailed explanations (understandable for a fish :D).

[Code 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzmuB.png)

[Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY80e.png)

[Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX62A.png)

Input_ID' and 'Attention_mask' are output values of the tokenizations process.

Comment: We need a bit more info to understand what is going on here. Which line raises the error? What are `input_ids` and `attention_mask`? The error in itself means that your script was expecting an iterable (a list, for example) with two elements inside, but it got one with a single element instead. Without more understanding of your code, it's impossible to guess. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: it also happens in case of empty strings or even strings, that the tokenizer doesn't know how to encode, for example " "

Answer (score 9):

It's a late answer but may help.

I had the same error. My problem was that 'input_ids' and 'attention_mask' have to be 2D tensor but I got them as 1D tensor. So do

```
input_ids = input_ids.unsqueeze(0)
attention_mask = attention_mask.unsqueeze(0)
```

in your case.

Answer (score 1):

BertModel expects a batch of training instances (e.g. input_id [[...][...]]). Hence, there should be no problem if you first batch your dataset (with sth like DataLoader) and iterate over it.

It seems like you given a single training instance (e.g. input_id [...]) for now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: tf batch worked for me.